# Which is the name of this kind of font, and how to use it?

Tags: math-fonts

I want to type the letter boxed by red box below
[image]

And I have tried several methods, such as $\mathcal{Y},$ $\mathscr{Y},$  but failed. I guess the letter is ``Y". How can I type it in tex? I have searched for solution, and found that usage of package mathpazo may help. But it changes all the main fonts of my file.

Comment: The picture seems to use Times for text and MathPazo for math: an example to not imitate.

Comment: @egreg Yes, it's true. But how can I do such that the text font is Times, while math font MathPazo?

Comment: Looks like the greek letter upsilon.